# prompt for password 3 times, if right=page1, wrong=page2

Tags: javascript

this is code from another forum, very thankful for it! its a password script. basically it operates by opening page1 then asking for the password and if entered right it opens page2 and if wrong after 3 tries it returns to page1. I like the way it looks, however, I need it modified so it keeps the look but operates like I want it to. how original script functions; page1 opens page2, on page2 button pressed, prompt asks for password, if right password entered then alert pops saying correct and button press and page3 open, if wrong password then prompt saying incorrect try again 2 more times and still if wrong password on 3rd try then returns to page1 and same if no password typed. what im hoping to get it to do; page1 opens page2, on page2 button pressed, prompt asks for password, if right password entered then alert pops saying correct and button press and page3 open, if wrong password then prompt saying incorrect try again 2 more times and still if wrong password on 3rd try then open page4 and same thing if no password typed but prompts clicked through. Here's original code;

```
<SCRIPT>
function passWord() {
var testV = 1;
var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password',' ');
while (testV < 3) {
if (!pass1) 
history.go(-1);
if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "letmein") {
alert('You Got it Right!');
window.open('protectpage.html');
break;
} 
testV+=1;
var pass1 = 
prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.','Password');
}
if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3) 
history.go(-1);
return " ";
} 
</SCRIPT>
<CENTER>
<FORM>
<input type="button" value="Enter Protected Area" onClick="passWord()">
</FORM>
</CENTER>
```

Here's what my modified script does; page1 opens page2, on page2 button pressed, prompt asks for password, if right password entered then alert pops saying correct and button press and page3 open, if wrong password then prompt saying incorrect try again 2 more times and still if wrong password on 3rd try then open page4 but if no password typed but clicked through it goes to page1. here's my modified script;

```
 <SCRIPT>
 function passWord() {
 var testV = 1;
 var pass1 = prompt('Type Your Answer',' ');
 while (testV < 3) {
 if (!pass1) 
 history.go(-1);
 if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "turn off") {
 alert('That Is Correct');
 window.open('code4TURNOFFresult.html','_top');
 break;
 } 
 testV+=1;
 var pass1 = 
 prompt('That Is Not Correct - Focus And Try Again',' ');
 window.open('code5TURNOFFfail.html','_top');
 }
 if (pass1.toLowerCase()!=" " & testV ==3)
 history.go(-1);
 return " ";
 } 
 </SCRIPT>
 <CENTER>
 <FORM>
 <input type="button" value="Click Me" onClick="passWord()">
 </FORM>
 </CENTER>
```

I think ive really explained this poorly, simple need is; I need script to ask for right password and if given then opens page1, if wrong password given you get 3 tries after 3rd try then opens page2 or if no password given after 3 tries then opens page2. anyone know if this script can be made to do this? thanks.

Comment: Add this line as the first line in your while loop `alert("pass1.toLowerCase() = " + pass1.toLowerCase());`. What does it tell you?

Comment: JavaScript uses two ampersands `&&` for AND, for one thing, `if (pass1.toLowerCase()!=" " && testV ==3)` you're also setting testV = 1 each time.

Comment: thanks jwpfox! added it right below the while statement. outcome; on page2 click button, prompts for answer; scenario1; right answer typed, prompt says "pass1.tolowercase()=whatwastyped, click ok, prompt says "that is correct", click ok, opens page3. (opening of page3 is good). scenario2; blank answer supplied, prompt says "pass1.tolowercase()=", click ok, repeats 2 times then opens page4.(opening of page4 is good). scenario3; wrong answer supplied, prompt says "pass1.tolowercase()=whatwastyped", click ok, repeats 2 times, opens page1(this is page before page2).

Comment: jwpfox & Patrick Moore thank you!! After my last post I was playing around with the code I posted. I removed all entries of HISTORY.GO and it now works! Here's what it does; from page2 scenario1; click button, prompt for pass, type correct pass, prompt says "correct", click button, opens page3. scenario2; click button, prompt for pass, type blank, prompt says "try again", repeat 2 times, opens page4. scenario3; click button, prompt for pass, type incorrect pass, prompt says "wrong try again", repeat 2 times, opens page4. I'll post the working code.

Comment: <SCRIPT>
 function passWord() {
 var testV = 1;
 var pass1 = prompt('Type Your Answer',' ');
 while (testV < 3) {
 if (!pass1); 
 if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "chosenpasswordhere") {
 alert('That Is Correct');
 window.open('page3.html','_top');
 break;
 } 
 testV+=1;
 var pass1 = 
 prompt('That Is Not Correct - Focus And Try Again',' ');
 window.open('page4.html','_top');
 }
 if (pass1.toLowerCase()!=" " && testV ==3);
 } 
 </SCRIPT>
 <CENTER>
 <FORM>
 <input type="button" value="Click Me" onClick="passWord()">
 </FORM>
 </CENTER>